# remove old version of eslint that causes a conflict

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, eslint, webpack-dev-server

When I run `npm run watch` I get this message `Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no):`

I type `y` then I get an error indicating a **conflict of eslint versions**

```html
npm ERR! Found: eslint@4.19.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^4.19.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-vue@5.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

*PS: I don't prefer to use `npm install --legacy-peer-dep` as workaround to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway, yet I need to delete it definitively*

is there a way to completly remove the old version so I won't get any troubles ?

[image]